# Issue getting information using XPath method in Selenium VBA Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am struggling getting the information of the name of a person in a website. Here is what I see when I inspect the page :

[image]

As you can see, I highlighted the line that I think is causing me some trouble. I don't know why when I select the line " **User : Piquemal Bruno**" (second line starting from the bottom) and I create an XPath I only have this :

/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5laQ4.png)/td[2]/b

I don't know why I don't have the previous information, as if it doesn't exists. Normally I should have this : /html/frameset/frame/document/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5laQ4.png)/td[2]/b

But something is blocking me from having the whole path.

```
Sub GetUserInfo()
    Dim k As WebElements
    Dim h As WebElement
    Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By

EdgeWeb.get """"INTERNET PAGE THAT I WANT""""
    
Set h = EdgeWeb.FindElementByName("banner")
Set k = EdgeWeb.FindElements(FindBy.XPath("/html/frameset/frame/document/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b"))

Debug.Print k.Count
End Sub
```

Here k is empty but h sees an element. Which is normal because the banner is just before the #document tag. It really looks like the #document tag is cutting the path.

I tried many other methods like FindElementByTag or FindElementByCSS but nothing works.

Hope you can help me and thank you beforehand.

Comment: What's the webpage? Do you need to switch into a different frame?

Comment: It's a webpage protected by a login... What do you mean a different frame?